# Unable to open connection to COM3 Error 5: access denied

Tags: serial-port

When I am using MOBAXTERM to connect to Orange PI 4 LTS through serial port, a prompt appears:
Unable to open connection to COM3
Opening '\.\COM3 ': Error 5: access denied

System: Windows 11 x64

I tried to run as an administrator, but it didn't work.